# Jquery - Check: If scroll possible (div with overflow:scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a little div with the css rules

```
width: 100px; height:100px;  overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;
```

How can i check -> if div scroll possible (aktiv)?

[A little example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3FFL/161/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

this:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append('content 1: ' + $('#my_div1').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 2: ' + $('#my_div2').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 3: ' + $('#my_div2').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 4: ' + $('#my_div2').hasScrollBar()+' <-- must be true <br />');
});
```

must be:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append('content 1: ' + $('#my_div1').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 2: ' + $('#my_div2').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 3: ' + $('#my_div3').hasScrollBar()+'<br />');
    $('body').append('content 4: ' + $('#my_div4').hasScrollBar()+' <-- must be true <br />');
});
```

Then result for `#my_div4` is `true` as expected. Small copy/paste error.

New jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/5kpvT/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and sorry for this stupid question :/